# C# Static Classes - A static class cannot have non-static members

Tags: c#, static, static-classes

I'm trying to understand the c# language and why you require the static keyword on all members within the static class. Yes, I understand a static class cannot be instantiated, but why aren't members ***by default static*** within a static class, as we know that a static class cannot have non-static members?

For Example: 
Why can't this

```
public static class StaticClass
{
    public static int numberTest = 2;
}
```

be:

```
public static class StaticClass2
{
    public int numberTest = 2;
}
```

Comment: The word static says it all. Static methods doesn't need an instance and that method needs to access the variable without the class instance.

Comment: Ah yes, an answer from Eric Lippert (in the linked answer) is fairly authoritative. :)

Comment: Agreed, read through the other thread with similar question and understand it... Just weird that I could not find it myself before posting the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely for historic reasons. You are right that an automatic, implied `static` would be more in line with other parts of the language.

But static classes were new in C# 2.0, and the change had to be non-breaking.

Comment: Also it seems better that adding the `static` modifier to a class declaration causes a compile error if some of the members are not static, rather than silently changing the behaviour of those members.

Comment: @MatthewWatson - it might have worked but the `static` modifier would have had to be disallowed on members (compare with `interface`). That would (kind of) break de-facto static classes written for C# 1.

Comment: Agreed (I removed my earlier comment as you were replying, sorry!)

Comment: Agreed and makes complete sense, however, it would be a different scenario on new static classes without any members... But accept the response

Comment: I found a dupe with an answer from Erric Lippert, he doesn't have to guess.

Comment: I will accept this answer based on the comments, however, the actual answer can be updated as well. Thanks @HenkHolterman

Answer (score 4):

It is a design decission by the language designers. Of course a `static` class can have `static` members only, so the `static` qualifier is *redundant*. But it makes things clearer and less error-prone if you are forced to put it there. This becomes more and more important when your classes and projects get larger.

Comment: Yes, I agree it is redundant, hence the question... I understand as a developer that it would be important in large projects, but I was just interested in knowing the reasons behind it.

Comment: In an interface the `public` modifier is implied and it is disallowed to add it yourself. There seems to be a parallel there, with different choices being made.